# JavaScript Redirect and IdHTTP

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy, indy10

When trying to login in to Hotmail I get a Javascript Redirect. Is there a way to avoid it?

```
IdHTTP1.Get('http://www.hotmail.com');
```

> **Cookies must be allowed** Your browser is currently set to block cookies. Your browser must allow cookies before you can use Windows
>   Live ID.
>
> Cookies are small text files stored on your computer that tell Windows
>   Live ID sites and services when you're signed in. To learn how to
>   allow cookies, see online help in your web browser.
>
> **JavaScript required to sign in** Windows Live ID requires JavaScript to sign in. This web browser either does not support JavaScript, or
>   scripts are being blocked.

Comment: What do you mean with _avoid the redirect_? to avoid it, simple ignore it!! :)

Comment: Is hard to figure out how are you processing that javascript redirect, your question doesn't mention how do you do. But you're using Indy, so no automatic javascript processing is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indy will not pass up a recognised user agent for you, you'd probably have to set that yourself. Also as it states you need JavaScript support, which Indy will not give you.

Your only real option is to automate something like IE, WebKit or Gecko or wrap some headless browser like PhantomJS.

Comment: even if you use a JS engine with it?

Comment: That might be possible, I could forsee lots of little quirks though that something like Hotmail would whinge about if it didn't find it.